# How to write nested JSON data to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write JSON data to Google Sheets but I believe it is not converting to the proper array list.

When I am doing `Logger.log(dataAll)`, I am getting the following response:

```
Logging output too large. Truncating output. {EmployeeLeaveTransactions=[{StartDateShift=Full Day, EmployeeCode=xxxx, Remarks=Personal, LeaveTypeCode=PrL, Approver1code=xxxx, Applicationtodate=31-12-2020, Reason=Personal, EndDateShift=Full Day, Numberofdays=10, AppliedDate=21-12-2020, LeaveTypeDescription=Privilege Leave, Status=Applied, Approver3code=, Applicationfromdate=22-12-2020, Approver2code=xxxx}, {Numberofdays=4, Approver1code=xxxx, AppliedDate=21-12-2020, Approver3code=, Reason=Personal, StartDateShift=Full Day, Remarks=, LeaveTypeCode=PrL, EmployeeCode=xxxx, Applicationfromdate=07-12-2020, Approver2code=xxxx, Applicationtodate=10-12-2020, LeaveTypeDescription=Privilege Leave, Status=Applied, EndDateShift=Full Day}, {AppliedDate=20-12-2020, EndDateShift=Full Day, Numberofdays=14, EmployeeCode=A00847, Approver2code=xxxx, StartDateShift=Full Day, Remarks=Personal, Approver1code=xxxx, LeaveTypeDescription=Privilege Leave, Approver3code=, Applicationtodate=13-12-2020, Reason=Personal, LeaveTypeCode=PrL, Status=Applied, Applicationfromdate=30-11-2020},
```

I have tried the below code so far, but don't how to write flatten data (in tabular form) to Google sheets

```
function leaveDetails() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dates');
  var url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  var toDate = ss.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  var fromDate = ss.getRange(1, 2).getValue();


  var data =
  {
    "SubscriptionName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Actionfromdate": fromDate,
    "Actiontodate": toDate,
    "Leavetypecode": "PrL"
  };

  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
    'payload': JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  var newData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(newData.getContentText());

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Master');
 
  var newArr = [];

  newArr.push(dataAll);

  Logger.log(dataAll);
  
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Write `dataAll` into a Google Sheet?

Comment: @ziganotschka,  I want to write this JSON data in Google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `dataAll` currently looks like

```
{EmployeeLeaveTransactions=[{StartDateShift=Full Day, EmployeeCode=xxxx, Remarks=Personal, LeaveTypeCode=PrL, Approver1code=xxxx, Applicationtodate=31-12-2020, Reason=Personal, EndDateShift=Full Day, Numberofdays=10, AppliedDate=21-12-2020, LeaveTypeDescription=Privilege Leave, Status=Applied, Approver3code=, Applicationfromdate=22-12-2020, Approver2code=xxxx}, {Numberofdays=4, Approver1code=xxxx, AppliedDate=21-12-2020, Approver3code=, Reason=Personal, StartDateShift=Full Day, Remarks=, LeaveTypeCode=PrL, EmployeeCode=xxxx, Applicationfromdate=07-12-2020, Approver2code=xxxx, Applicationtodate=10-12-2020, LeaveTypeDescription=Privilege Leave, Status=Applied, EndDateShift=Full Day}, {AppliedDate=20-12-2020, EndDateShift=Full Day, Numberofdays=14, EmployeeCode=A00847, Approver2code=xxxx, StartDateShift=Full Day, Remarks=Personal, Approver1code=xxxx, LeaveTypeDescription=Privilege Leave, Approver3code=, Applicationtodate=13-12-2020, Reason=Personal, LeaveTypeCode=PrL, Status=Applied, Applicationfromdate=30-11-2020},...
```

defining
`var EmployeeLeaveTransactions = dataAll.EmployeeLeaveTransactions`
should result in an array like

```js
  [
    {
      "StartDateShift":"Full Day",
      "EmployeeCode":"xxxx",
      "Remarks":"Personal",
      "LeaveTypeCode":"PrL"
      ...
    },
      {
      "Numberofdays":4, 
      "Approver1code":"xxxx", 
      "AppliedDate":"21-12-2020",    
      ...
    } 
   ]
```

When you log it, the log will look like:

```
[{EmployeeCode=xxxx, StartDateShift=Full Day,...}, {Approver1code=xxxx, Numberofdays=4.0,...}]
```

On this kind of object you can use the [object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to access the key values pairs contained in the JSON object and to pass them into an array that you can use to write into Google sheets.

Sample:

```js
var EmployeeLeaveTransactions = dataAll.EmployeeLeaveTransactions;
var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i< EmployeeLeaveTransactions.length; i++){
    var newJson = Object.keys(EmployeeLeaveTransactions[i]).map(function (key) { 
      return [key, EmployeeLeaveTransactions[i][key]]; 
    }); 
    for(var j = 0; j< newJson.length; j++){
      array.push(newJson[j]);
    }
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1, array.length, array[0].length);
  range.setValues(array);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! @ziganotschka, but it is not working.  
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. I believe EmployeeLeaveTransactions not supporting length property.

Comment: I am sorry - obviously I cannot know the exact structure of your object, I updated my answer to explain more in detail of what it should look like to be able to run the code sample - basically it needs to be an array to support length property. Depending on what your object looked like before - you might need to JSON parse it / perform another action. What does `EmployeeLeaveTransactions` look like when you log it? And `Logger.log(typeof EmployeeLeaveTransactions)`? It should not be a string.